# When is $M\otimes N$ a module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

So suppose we have a $R$-$S$-bimodule $M$, and an $S$-$T$ bimodule $N$, then we can construct the abelian group $M\otimes_S N$. Under what conditions could we make this a module?

I would expect this to be the case if $R=S=T$, but are there weaker conditions which would do the job?

Comment: An abelian group is always a $\mathbb Z$-module.  But the tensor product is actually an $R-T$-bimodule.

Comment: $M\otimes_SN$ is naturally an $R$-$T$-bimodule *always*. This should be explained in every good textbook treating tensor products.

Comment: Textip: do not write `$R-S$-bimodule`, as the spacing and length of the dashes comes out **incredibly** wrong: the correct way to write that in TeX is `$R$-$S$-bimodule`, which gives «$R$-$S$-bimodule».

Comment: Many thanks to all the replies!

Comment: As it has been mentioned in the above comments $M\otimes_SN$ is an $R$-$T$ bimodule with the following actions; let $r\in R$ , $t\in T$ and $m\otimes n\in M\otimes_SN$ ( a pure tensor) we have  
$$r.(m\otimes n)=r.m\otimes n$$ and $$(m\otimes n).t=m\otimes (n.t)$$

Comment: @Math137 You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been mentioned in the above comments, $M\otimes_SN$ is an $R$-$T$ bimodule with the following actions; let $r\in R$ , $t\in T$ and $m\otimes n\in M\otimes_SN$ ( a pure tensor) we have
$$r.(m\otimes n)=r.m\otimes n$$
and
$$(m\otimes n).t=m\otimes(n.t)$$
these actions are also compatible, since $r.((m\otimes n).t)=r.(m\otimes(n.t))=(r.m)\otimes(n.t)=(r.(m\otimes n)).t$